# Command line sys.argv [1]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a python script with command line "date"

why do I get a number when I introduce `sys.argv[1]`

```
import sys
xDate=sys.argv[1]
print(xDate)
43263

sys.version
Out[134]: '3.5.3 |Intel Corporation| (default, Apr 27 2017, 18:08:47) \n[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)]'
```

Comment: Can you show your terminal log? What exactly are you putting as your command line argument?

Comment: here is what I put in the terminal:  python originalPAGquery.py 2018-04-19

Comment: thank you. May I ask. how can we run the command line if we use ipython  exec(open("originalPAGquery.py").read())  '2018-04-10'   this command does not work

Comment: You're saying that you run `python originalPAGquery.py 2018-04-19` in your terminal, and the contents of *originalPAGquery.py* is the code above, and you get that output? Hard to believe. Your code and output are interleaved which tells me that you're in the *Python* interpreter. What happens if you `print(sys.argv)` after `import sys`?